# What is SO2Ar as a functional group and how is it relevant in this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds

[image: Corresponding reaction]

This reaction came up in one of my problem sessions and I had never seen an SO2Ar function group before. What are it's general properties and how is it relevant to this reaction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\ce{-SO2Ar}$ means a [sulfonyl group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfonyl) with an aryl ring attached to the sulfur.

It is totally irrelevant to this reaction. Your first step is to add the methoxide into the carbonyl group. Then collapse the tetrahedral intermediate.

Comment: Sulfonamide (NHSO2R) is an acid isostere, the proton on the N is pretty acidic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Zhe has indicated the first step is attack of methoxide on the carbonyl group. The tetrahedral intermediate collapses and sulfonamide anion (ArSO2N-) leaves giving the methyl ester. The sulfonamide anion then attacks the C-Br intramolecularly forming the product shown. This works because sulfonamide NH is acidic (pKa ~ 16) and the anion is a pretty stable species.